# How to load different youtube videos, based on ID, with javascript, on button clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

(SOLVED)

I'm trying to create several buttons which all will play a different embedded background youtube video.

Right now, what happens when I click one of the buttons is:

```
function changeMission(id) {            
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
}
```

And then:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    selectedVideoId = getVideoId();

    player = new YT.Player('player', {      
        frameborder:'0',
        playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque'},
        videoId: selectedVideoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.setVolume(30);
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {     
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); 
    }
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
}
```

The original thought I had was that I could just load different videoIDs based on which button is clicked, but as I understand it now, that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it on my own, but in case someone else gets this problem:

use the player.loadVideoById(videoId); function. It takes some fiddling around, but it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the player.loadVideoById(videoId); function.